# MongoDB not that faster than MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, mongodb

I discovered mongodb some months ago,and after reading this [post](http://www.vedana.it/it/component/content/article/9-linux/62-testing-mongodb-vs-mysql-with-python-scripting-under-linux), I thought mongodb was really faster than mysql, so I decided to build my own bench, the problem is that I do not have the same result than the above post's author, especially for quering the database : mongodb seems to be slower than MyISAM tables. Could you have a look to my python code, may be there is something wrong in it :

```
from datetime import datetime
import random
import MySQLdb
import pymongo

mysql_db=MySQLdb.connect(user="me",passwd="mypasswd",db="test_kv")
c=mysql_db.cursor()

connection = pymongo.Connection()
mongo_db = connection.test
kvtab = mongo_db.kvtab

nb=1000000
thelist=[]
for i in xrange(nb):
    thelist.append((str(random.random()),str(random.random())))
t1=datetime.now()

for k,v in thelist:
    c.execute("INSERT INTO key_val_tab (k,v) VALUES ('" + k + "','" + v + "')")

dt=datetime.now() - t1
print 'MySQL insert elapse :',dt

t1=datetime.now()
for i in xrange(nb):
    c.execute("select * FROM key_val_tab WHERE k='" + random.choice(thelist)[0] + "'")
    result=c.fetchone()

dt=datetime.now() - t1
print 'MySQL select elapse :',dt


t1=datetime.now()

for k,v in thelist:
    kvtab.insert({"key":k,"value":v})

dt=datetime.now() - t1
print 'Mongodb insert elapse :',dt
kvtab.ensure_index('key')
t1=datetime.now()
for i in xrange(nb):
    result=kvtab.find_one({"key":random.choice(thelist)[0]})

dt=datetime.now() - t1
print 'Mongodb select elapse :',dt
```

Notes:

- both MySQL and mongodb are on locahost.
- both MySQL and mongodb has the 'key' column indexed

MySQL Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `key_val_tab` (
  `k` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
  `v` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
  KEY `kindex` (`k`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Versions are:

- MySQL: 5.1.41
- mongodb : 1.8.3
- python : 2.6.5
- pymongo : 2.0.1
- Linux : Ubuntu 2.6.32 32Bits with PAE
- Hardware : Desktop core i7 2.93 Ghz

Results (for 1 million inserts/selects) :

```
MySQL insert elapse : 0:02:52.143803
MySQL select elapse : 0:04:43.675914
Mongodb insert elapse : 0:00:49.038416  -> mongodb much faster for insert
Mongodb select elapse : 0:05:10.409025  -> ...but slower for quering (thought was the opposite)
```

Comment: For one, MongoDB likes a 64bit architecture. I wouldn't put much stock in a benchmark run by someone who isn't very experienced with one of the systems being benchmarked.

Comment: that's why I asked some help !

Comment: @ceejayoz If you have to be very experienced to make it go fast, then it will be slow for most users. I'd say benchmarks made by inexperienced users might be just as useful...

Comment: I'm not sure the be-all-end all goal of mongodb (and other nosql dbs) are to be faster than sql servers, especially in a single server scenario. Most nosql dbs are built to scale vertically,, you'll likely see bigger improvements when you need to partition your data over 10 SQL dbs vs 10 nosql dbs

Comment: Did you profile to find out where all the time is being spent?  Is `kvtab.find_one` really the slow spot?  Or is this wasting time creating Python dict objects? do be used when doing `kvtab.find_one`?  The problem with database benchmarks is that you may be measuring inefficiency in the benchmark itself.

Comment: in addition to @eric, these programs seem to address different scenarios which happen to overlap at SOME aspects. i don't think such a comparison is "fare" without addressing business considerations, type of software and data, etc.

Comment: @Ivar Bonsaksen If you're experienced with MySQL but not with MongoDB, expect MySQL to have a better chance of doing well. You can't jump into a new tech in production usage without learning how to optimize it.

Comment: It doesn't seem like a very extensive benchmark.  Firstly, you only have 1 client, and inserts and selects aren't even being done at the same time.  MyISAM can start really slowing down once you are trying to updates at the same time as selects, because inserts and updates require the table to be locked.

Comment: Have you checked that you're using the C extensions to pymongo? You can test this quickly by running `python -c 'import pymongo; print pymongo.has_c(); import bson; print bson.has_c()'` at the command line; it should print `True` twice. The pure-python BSON encoder/decoder should be nearly as fast as C in pymongo 2.1, but is significantly slower in the current releases.

Comment: @ceejayoz I have to agree with you there. If you are to make a novice benchmark, you should be equally unfamiliar with all technologies involved:) But, as this question shows, readers of such benchmarks will probably get more useful information from the comments than the benchmark itself.

Answer (score 31):

Sigh. These kind of benchmarks, and I use the term loosely in this case, usually break down from the very start. MySQL isn't a "slower" database than MongoDB. One is a relational database, the other a NoSQL document store. They will/should be faster in the functional areas that they were designed to cover. In the case of MySQL (or any RDBMS) and MongoDB this overlap isn't as big as a lot of people assume it is. It's the same kind of broken apples and oranges comparison you get with Redis vs. MongoDB discussions.

There are so many variables (app functional requirements, hardware resources, concurrency, configuration, scalability, etc.) to consider that any benchmark or article that ends with "MongoDB is faster than MySQL" or vice versa is generalizing results to the point of uselessness.

If you want to do benchmark first define a strict set of functional requirements and business rules and then implement them as efficiently as possible on both persistence solutions. The result will be that one is faster than the other and in almost all cases the faster approach has some relevant downsides that might still make the slower solution more viable depending on requirements.

All this is ignoring that the benchmark above doesn't simulate any sort of real world scenario. There wont be a lot of apps doing max throughput inserts without any sort of threading/concurrency (which impacts performance on most storage solutions significantly).

Finally, comparing inserts like this is a little broken too. MongoDB can achieve amazing insert throughput with fire and forget bulk inserts or can be orders of magnitude slower with fsynced, replicated writes. The thing here is that MongoDB offers you a choice where MySQL doesn't (or less so). So here the comparison only make sense of the business requirements allow for fire and forget type writes (Which boil down to, "I hope it works, but no biggy if it didn't")

TL;DR stop doing simple throughput benchmarks. They're almost always useless.

Comment: +1 for an excellent answer, I just wanted to add that MySQL offers plethora of storage engines - one of them being TokuDB that uses fractal trees to achieve excellent insert speed.

Comment: In the interest of full disclosure I'd like to add here that I'm a huge MongoDB fan. But it isn't the magic database bullet for everything, nor does 10gen claim it to be.

Comment: I completely agree with you, however it's usually the lack of knowledge that determines popularity of a certain piece of software. One reads that MongoDB does [insert number of QPS] more than [insert something completely functionally unrelated to MongoDB] and all of a sudden internet's polluted with "X is better than Y", benchmarked by people without real work experience. Right tool for the right job should be any programmer's mantra.

Comment: Well, the goal of my question was not to prove that mongodb is not that fast with a such rapid single test. But to understand why my 'select' elapse times for mongo is 20x slower than the post I gave the link in the beginning of my question : The author was using python like me, and had much more rapid searches than me, so why ?

Comment: (better) indexes, right balancing, faster disk i/o, more memory, data cardinality, etc.

Comment: Also, it is a little questionable to downvote an answer to your own question. If you feel the answer is incorrect comment on why you feel this is. If not accept this and open a new question that is perhaps more focused. In other words, don't shoot the messenger.

Answer (score 7):

```
MySQL insert elapse : 0:02:52.143803
Mongodb insert elapse : 0:00:49.038416  -> mongodb much faster for insert
```

Mongodb inserts much faster because of mongodb insert all data into ram and then periodically flush data to the disc.

```
MySQL select elapse : 0:04:43.675914
Mongodb select elapse : 0:05:10.409025  -> ...but slower for quering (thought was
```

You can achieve best performance with mongodb when you will embedd/denormalize your data. In many situation mongodb allow us to avoid joins because of embedding/denormalization.

And when you just inserting data into one collection/table and reading back by index mongodb not supposed to be faster, read speed should be ~ same if compare with sql database.

BTW: In mongodb 2.0 [indexes](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/2.0+Release+Notes#2.0ReleaseNotes-IndexPerformanceEnhancements) 25% faster, so i guess 2.0 will work faster then mysql.

Comment: inserts are faster because it doesn't do what MySQL does. safe=true inserts are a bit slower (bit generally still faster than MySQL) and replicated writes or fsync writes are slower still. Point being, comparisons like these are questionable. They do wildly different things.

Comment: I agree with you, but i am not comparing, I've just said why in his benchmark mongodb faster. Because of by default safe=false and it's mean on flush per minute.

Answer (score 2):

It's wrong to look at python execution time and estimate database quality. Each request consist of at least 3 parts:

- request preparing (client side),
- request execution (server),
- response preparing (client side)

By my experience data convertion for MongoDB=>python takes much more time than for MySQL=>python.

Also you should use indexes in both databases. MongoDB works good only if you have indexes on fields that you use for queries.
Talking about MySQL, I think it's better to test performance on innoDB, MyISAM doesn't support transactions, foreign keys, triggers and as for me it's a little bit outdated.

Comment: As I want to use python, I care about database+python, not database only.